# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:

Tags: laravel

I have a problem only when updating (not creating)
I got this error :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime
> format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column
> `alleshops`.`eshops`.`payathome` at row 1 (SQL: update `eshops` set
> `payathome` = on, `paywithcard` = on, `eshops`.`updated_at` =
> 2021-01-17 05:33:03 where `id` = 10)

Here is my controller:

```
public function edit_eshop(Eshop $eshop,Request $request){
    if ($request->method() == 'POST'){                       
        $eshop->title = $request->get('title');
        $eshop->link = $request->get('link');
        $eshop->telephone = $request->get('telephone');
        $eshop->email = $request->get('email');
        $eshop->payathome = $request->get('payathome');
        $eshop->paywithcard = $request->get('paywithcard');
        $eshop->tags = $request->get('tags');
        if($eshop->save()){
            echo "Το eshop δημιουργήθηκε επιτυχώς.";
            return redirect('/eshops');
        };
    };        
    return view('edit_eshop', ['eshop' => $eshop]);
}
```

similar questions didn't help me unfortunatelly

Comment: seems like `payathome` in your form is a checkbox? is this field supposed to be a datetime field in the database?

Comment: Yes it is a checkbox. In the database is integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `dd($request->all())` to visualize the user's request payload.

Based on your problem, I think the problem is in `$request->get('payathome')`. It is not an integer value, I don't care about the input field, but it tells us that `payathome` data is a string. Try to convert it, just like:
`$eshop->payathome = $request->get('payathome')=="on"?1:0;`

Hope this help you. Happy Code!

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me where "on" came from? In the form there is no "on" !

Comment: @AlexGk 'on' is the default value of a checkbox if one isn't set

Comment: you could also test if the input was passed at all (checked state) `$request->has('payathome')`